# Obtaining moments from the inverse of moment-generating function?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I know that the inverse of my moment generating function is the following:

$$\frac{z}{(1+z)^5}$$

Inverting this expression appears hard, is there an easier way to get the moments?

I expect them to be 1, 5, 35, 285, 2530,... because of formula 3.54 in [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf)

Comment: I just looked up the sequence and found it in OEIS. https://oeis.org/A002294

Comment: @user25406 looks like it comes out of [series reversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287953/obtaining-moments-from-the-inverse-of-the-moment-generating-function#comment716867_287953)